# Kittel solid state physics handbook - Plasma oscillation of a ball - Am I solving this right?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, classical-electrodynamics, plasma-physics, plasmon

I'm self learning nanotechnology undergraduate and I'm trying to solve a problem from chapter "plasmons, polaritons and polarons".

This is it:

> Frequency of uniform mode of plasmons in a ball is determined by depolarisation field $E=-4\pi P/3 $ where polarisation $P=-ner$ with $r$ being mean displacement of electrons with concentration $n$. Show that resonant frequency $\omega ^2_0=4\pi ne^2/3m$ using $F=ma$

So I replaced $r$ with $x$ and wrote:

$x=A sin(\omega t)$

$a=x''=-A \omega^2sin(\omega t)$

$F=Ee$

Since $F=ma$ I can write $Ee=-mA\omega^2sin(\omega t)$

$-4\pi Pe/3 = -mA\omega^2sin(\omega t)$

$-4\pi ne^2x/3=mA\omega^2sin(\omega t)$

$\omega^2=(-4\pi ne^2)/(3m)*x/(Asin(\omega t))$

So my answer resembles correct answer except I got a minus sign before final solution and  this remaining $x/sin(\omega t)$

What I did wrong? And does my method make sense? How to remove the remaining term? Where did I loose minus sign?

Comment: It's my translation, because my mother tongue and my book's language isn't english. In my edition it is chapter 10 question 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to solve this completely for you, but note just a few things:

1. The charge of an electron is negative
2. In a simple harmonic oscillator, the force must be in a direction opposite to the displacement
3. You had earlier set $x=A\sin\omega t$ so it seems to me that $\frac{x}{A\sin\omega t}=1$

I think that if you ponder the above you will see where your minus sign comes from (or where it has to go...). You know of course that $\omega^2>0$ when the oscillation is "real".

Comment: <grabs my head and says ooooooohhhhhhhhh>
Great thanks!